# Returned JSON in Orientdb Using Function

Tags: javascript, json, api, orientdb

I tried to execute this code using functions at OrientDB Studio.

```
commandResult = db.executeCommand('insert into user (facebookId,instagramId) values ("' + facebookId +'","'+ instagramId +'");


if( commandResult.length == 0){
 response.send(200, "ok", "application/json","{\"success\":\"false\"}");
} else {
  response.send(200, "ok", "application/json","{\"success\":\"true\", \"@rid\" : \"" +  commandResult  + "\"}");
```

}

and then it returns like this
`{"success":"true", "@rid" : "user#11:15{facebookId:df,instagramId:sdf} v1"}`

My problem now is i want only to return only the rid value. But the problem is in my second key `"user#11:15{facebookId:df,instagramId:sdf} v1"`. I don't know how am I going to parse it since the `@rid` is in the outside of the curly brace.

Hope from your positive response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating strings. Use the .toJSON() instead:

```
response.send(200, "ok", "application/json",
"{ \"success\":\"true\", \"@rid\" : \"" + 
 commandResult.toJSON()  + "\"}");
```